# Json Array is giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, arrays, nullpointerexception

Parent Layout:
Here I am creating an array inside an object for data.And data is inserted in child part.

```
if (((ProxyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).
    getPreferences().
    getStringAttributes(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.SCANNED_STUDENT_LIST_DATA)
    != null)
  try {
    mContext.jsonObject = new JSONObject(((ProxyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).
        getPreferences().
        getStringAttributes(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.SCANNED_STUDENT_LIST_DATA).toString());
    array = mContext.jsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.JSON_ARRAY);
    for (int count = 0; count < array.length(); count++) {
      ((ProxyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext())
          .addScannedStudentList(new ResponseParserManager()
              .parseArrayStudentList(mContext, array.getJSONObject(count)));
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
else {
  mContext.jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  array = new JSONArray();
  try {
    mContext.jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.JSON_ARRAY,
        array);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Child:

```
Student stObject = new ResponseParserManager().parseResponse(result.getText());
try {

  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result.getText());
  object.put(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.BRANCH_NAME,
      ((ProxyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).getPreferences()
          .getStringAttributes(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.BRANCH_NAME));
  object.put(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.YEAR,
      ((ProxyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).getPreferences()
          .getStringAttributes(AppConstants.SharePreferencesConstants.YEAR));
  array.put(object);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here at array.put I am getting an exception of null pointer after debugging object is showing all the values and array is instantiated properly but showing exception while working.

> Log :Process:                                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.json.JSONArray.isNull(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                        at .fragments.ContinousScanFragment$1.barcodeResult(ContinousScanFragment.java:114)
>                                                                                                        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView$WrappedCallback.barcodeResult(DecoratedBarcodeView.java:49)
>                                                                                                        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView$1.handleMessage(BarcodeView.java:52)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Comment: Please post your crash log. Also check what are the chances that your array is not initialised.

Comment: Its initialized actually because while debugging pointer is initializing the array.

Comment: Please provide complete crash log.

Comment: Updated log @am110787. Please help me out it would be much help if you can tell me any possible solution as i am in middle of my project.

Comment: Try `array =  new JSONArray()` before  array.put(object); or put a check `if(array != null) { array.put(object);}`

Comment: Actually the thing is am implementing a global array in parent and putting object from child ! while putting object in array from child class ! compiler is throwing an exception ! so cant create a new instance because i need to have that global array only .